# Office.js - OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64 throws exception with Word 2016

Tags: office-js

I have used following code for parsing Word document in an office app

```
var currentSlice = currentFile.getSliceAsync(0, function (resultSlice) {
   if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
  //We got the file slice. Now we will encode the data and post to a service
  var documentText = OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64(resultSlice.value);
  // Open the document, which is stored as a base64 string.
  var doc = new openXml.OpenXmlPackage(documentText);
   }
}
```

this works for Word 2013 but following line

```
OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64(resultSlice.value);
```

throws exception

> Object doesn't support property or method 'charCodeAt'

on Word 2016.

Any idea about what are possible reasons?

Note i have used the latest Office.js from https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js

Regards,
Jhan Zaib

Comment: What's the type of `resultSlice.value`? You might need to call `toString()` on that.

Comment: yes tried to call toString() but the code break on line

var doc = new openXml.OpenXmlPackage(documentText);

now exception raised "Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory"

Comment: Even though I may not have the answer I think you should take a look here.  It may point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332855/how-to-insert-an-image-into-word-from-a-url

Answer (score 2):

The OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64(resultSlice.value); is intended to be used internally for Office.js consumption and it will not behave as you are expecting. Its not just encoding to base64.  there are many libraries out there (available as freeware) that will help you encode the result of getSliceAsync (binary stream) into a base64 encoded string.